# karate signal and listen across feature files

Tags: java, karate

I am trying to write a test for an async webhook callback using karate.signal and karate.listen as documented at https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master#async
I have split the test into two feature files. One for making the request from karate and one from handling the request on karate. However the listen is always timing out even if the signal call is made.

Test feature file

```
Feature: Check Redis Event Q impl

  Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * def startmock = (mockName) => karate.start({mock:mockName,port:mockServerPort}).port
    * def mockServerUrl = 'http://localhost:'+ startmock('localTestServer.mock') +'/api/response'

  Scenario: Run ack immediately

    Given path servicePrefix, 'testq'
    And request { cbUrl:'#(mockServerUrl)' , deferCount : 0, deferSecs:0 }
    When method POST
    Then status 200
    * listen 1000
    * print listenResult
    * json data = listenResult
    * match data.count == 0
```

Mock server feature file

```
Feature: stateful mock server

  Background:

    * def prop = function(name){ return java.lang.System.getProperty(name) }
    * def uuid = function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '' }
    * print "started mock"


  Scenario: pathMatches('/api/response') && methodIs('post')
    * def responseStatus = 200
    * print 'signalling'
    * karate.signal(request)
    * print 'signalled'

# This a catch all scenario handles every request, that hasn't been handled before.
  Scenario:
    * print 'No dedicated scenario matches incoming request.'
    * print 'With Headers:'
    * print requestHeaders
    * print 'With Request Parameters'
    * print requestParams
    * print 'And Request:'
    * print request
    * def responseStatus = 404
    * def response = {status:'OK'}
```

However the listen always times out and is not getting the signalled object . The logs seem to indicate that the listen and signal are happening but the listen is always timing out

Log snippet

```
    10:59:23.721 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - entered listen state with timeout: 1000
    10:59:23.776 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.a.connect.bridge.http.HttpClient - Doing POST to url http://localhost:60812/api/response with body {"count":0,"time":0} and headers DefaultHttpHeaders[x-request-id: f9f0a598-fef3-4cc6-8c7e-a42c9aafa551, x-trail: e0c13a9f-0bdd-43a2-97a3-f79e52731f67;MISC_Q_c2715d2e-684a-46dd-9408-89d308c2f6cd;f9f0a598-fef3-4cc6-8c7e-a42c9aafa551, content-type: application/json]
    10:59:23.886 [armeria-common-worker-nio-9-1] INFO  c.l.a.i.common.JavaVersionSpecific - Using the APIs optimized for: Java 9+
    10:59:23.925 [armeria-common-worker-nio-9-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - scenario matched at line 10: pathMatches('/api/response') && methodIs('post')
    10:59:23.928 [armeria-common-worker-nio-9-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] signalling 
    10:59:23.938 [armeria-common-worker-nio-9-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] signalled 
    10:59:23.950 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.a.c.c.w.RedisQTestEventProcessor - Finished Event
    10:59:23.956 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.a.c.b.worker.redisq.LeaseHandler - Worker Task Done
    10:59:24.725 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - listen timed out: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    10:59:24.726 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - exit listen state with result: null
```

Full logs

```
10:59:23.435 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - request:
1 > POST http://localhost:60811//testq
1 > Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
1 > Content-Length: 80
1 > Host: localhost:60811
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.20.1)
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
{"cbUrl":"http:\/\/localhost:60812\/api\/response","deferCount":0,"deferSecs":0}

10:59:23.547 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] INFO  c.a.c.bridge.http.HttpRequestHandler - Got body {"cbUrl":"http:\/\/localhost:60812\/api\/response","deferCount":0,"deferSecs":0}
10:59:23.657 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] INFO  c.a.c.b.w.redisq.WorkerPollerMgr - Q Insert
10:59:23.713 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] INFO  c.a.c.bridge.http.RequestIdStamper - done
10:59:23.719 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 283
1 < 200
1 < content-length: 15
1 < content-type: text/plain
1 < x-request-id: e0c13a9f-0bdd-43a2-97a3-f79e52731f67
EmptyResource{}

10:59:23.721 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - entered listen state with timeout: 1000
10:59:23.776 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.a.connect.bridge.http.HttpClient - Doing POST to url http://localhost:60812/api/response with body {"count":0,"time":0} and headers DefaultHttpHeaders[x-request-id: f9f0a598-fef3-4cc6-8c7e-a42c9aafa551, x-trail: e0c13a9f-0bdd-43a2-97a3-f79e52731f67;MISC_Q_c2715d2e-684a-46dd-9408-89d308c2f6cd;f9f0a598-fef3-4cc6-8c7e-a42c9aafa551, content-type: application/json]
10:59:23.886 [armeria-common-worker-nio-9-1] INFO  c.l.a.i.common.JavaVersionSpecific - Using the APIs optimized for: Java 9+
10:59:23.925 [armeria-common-worker-nio-9-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - scenario matched at line 10: pathMatches('/api/response') && methodIs('post')
10:59:23.928 [armeria-common-worker-nio-9-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] signalling 
10:59:23.938 [armeria-common-worker-nio-9-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] signalled 
10:59:23.950 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.a.c.c.w.RedisQTestEventProcessor - Finished Event
10:59:23.956 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.a.c.b.worker.redisq.LeaseHandler - Worker Task Done
10:59:24.725 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - listen timed out: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
10:59:24.726 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - exit listen state with result: null
10:59:24.732 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] null 
10:59:24.733 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - classpath:com/eventq/eventq.feature:16
* json data = listenResult
cannot convert to json: [type: NULL, value: null]
classpath:com/eventq/eventq.feature:16
---------------------------------------------------------
feature: classpath:com/eventq/eventq.feature
scenarios:  1 | passed:  0 | failed:  1 | time: 1.6729
---------------------------------------------------------


org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: cannot convert to json: [type: NULL, value: null]
```

I am using karate version 1.2.0

Comment: sorry I pass on this. if you follow this process, people could try it locally and debug etc: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Filed an issue with a minimal example at https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2412